# Implementing a JList from custom objects efficiently?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, custom-component

I need to implement a JList to display the contents of an Array-List. The ArrayList contains "custom" objects, from which I only want to display the title.

A "custom object" can have
- title
- user
etc.

What would be the most efficient way to do this as opposed to what I'm doing now (going through the entire array and building another array of strings with title[i] = customObject.getTitle())?

Thanks to anyone who will take the time to answer...

Comment: Read the [Javadoc of the JList class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html). It explain it all: model and rendering. No need to create an extra-array containing all your "titles".

Answer (score 3):

- there no restrictions, bug in the code, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), demonstraded your issue(s)
- (don't reinvent the wheel) create a [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html) that hold value for [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- all updates to the `ListModel` must be done on [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- for most complex output to the GUI or array is based on `java.util.List`, `Map`, `HashMap`, then to use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) with one column based on [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), because `JList` has implemented reduced methods or features in compare with `JTable`